# Not able to set key to the object inside for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am trying to push into an array and want to set a key(`dayOfWeek`) to `obj` inside for loop.

```
let array = []
const obj = { 'away': '17:30', 'sleep': '20:30' }
for (let room of rooms) {
  let days = []
  room.schedules.map(s => days.push(s.dayOfWeek))
  days = new Set(days)
  for(let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    obj.dayOfWeek = i
    console.log(obj)
    if(!days.has(i)) array.push(obj)
  }
}
```

But when I log `obj` I always get `dayOfWeek` value equal to `7`

Please help what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only ever have *one* object in memory - you're pushing multiple references to the same object to the array, while reassigning that object's `dayOfWeek` property. Instead, *clone* the object while pushing, so that the array has *separate* objects:

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  if(!days.has(i)) {
    array.push({
      ...obj,
      dayOfWeek: i
    });
  }
}
```

Also note that if you use `.map`, you should use the resulting mapped array, rather than `push`ing to an external array:

```
let days = room.schedules.map(s => s.dayOfWeek);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What does `...` mean in javascript?

Comment: That's spread syntax - it *spreads* each property in the spreaded object into the new object. (It's an easier way of writing `array.push(Object.assign({}, obj, { dayOfWeek: i }));`)

Comment: Thank that's new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have only 1 instance of `obj`, and you change the value of `dayOfWeek`, every iteration of the loop, so it will have the last value written (i.e 7).

Instead, create a new `obj` for each iteration.